# Object.create not creating properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype

I have the following function

```
const Admins = function(users, affiliation) {
    this.users = users;
    this.affiliation = affiliation;
}
Admins.prototype.filterAffiliation = function _filterAffiliation() {
    const filtered = this.users.filter( (user) => {
        return user.affiliation === this.affiliation;
    });
    console.log(filtered); // this shows the array of users filtered
    return Object.create(this, { users: filtered });
}

const admins = new Admins(users, affiliation);
console.log(admins);  // this shows everything correctly... 
admins.filterAffiliation() // this shows { users: undefined }
```

If I change the `Object.create(this, {users: filtered})` with `this.users = filtered; return this;` it "works", but I don't want to change the state of my original object. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe use `Object.assign` instead?

Comment: I tried it. The problem with Object.assign is that it doesn't makes a deep copy

Comment: @tupan `Object.create` doesn't make a deep copy either. It's quite unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe you're actually looking for `return  new Admins(filtered)`?

Comment: The first argument to `Object.create` should be the prototype to use for the newly constructed object. Why are you using `Object.create` here instead of simply `return { users: filtered }`?

Comment: @Bergi, while it doesn't make a deep copy, Object.create provides the ability to receive a prototype which does what I need.

Comment: @user633183, no that is different than what I need. I need to access the object later on so I can use chain calls, like `admin1.filter1().filter2().add(user).del(user)`... if you don't know what I want, don't assume things. The answer was provided and accepted hours ago.

Comment: @tupan If you want to provide method chaining, then you *really* should construct a `new Admins` instance. Not use `Object.create` to make an object which *inherits from* an instance (or even worse, a deep prototype chain linking many objects).

Comment: It's great point, @Bergi! Thanks for the suggestion/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "properties" optional argument to `Object.create()` should not be just an ordinary object. Instead, it should look like the argument to `Object.defineProperties()`:

```
   return Object.create(this, {
     users: { value: filtered }
   });
```

And if you want the property to be enumerable and writable etc, you have to explicitly mention that:

```
   return Object.create(this, {
     users: { 
       value: filtered,
       enumerable: true,
       writable: true
     }
   });
```

As is pointed out in a comment below, having that function return a new object created with the called context as the prototype sure looks strange. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just

```
   return new Admin(filtered, this.affiliation);
```

or something else less exotic.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't very clear from where I was taking my information (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: This still looks like a misuse of `Object.create` and I'm inclined to downvote it

Comment: @user633183 ?? It's a [documented feature.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.create)

Comment: @Pointy, I mean the way the OP is using it. Passing `this` as the prototype for the new object is going to have strange, probably unintended, side effects. The OP's intentions are not clear. Providing answers like this one can be harmful because we "helped" the OP do something the wrong way.

Comment: @user633183 ah well that may be the case; I'm not sure what the goal of the OP is in doing that. It's not *necessarily* wrong in general, but you're right that the OP may be going down a dubious path.

Comment: Right, the only reason your answer uses `Object.create` is because the OP originally used it in the question. As helpers, I think it's our goal to understand what the OP truly needs, before serving them a bowl of their own bad soup.

Comment: Answer updated with what I think might be better, though it's still muddy. And while I agree with your sentiment, aside from the situation in which `Object.create()` happens to be used here, the thing about what the "properties" argument needs to look like might still be useful for somebody doing something less weird.